# MS migration tool -dropbox parent folder name

Tags: migration, sharepoint-online, dropbox, data-migration

When migrating data from Dropbox to SharePoint with the online MS migration tool from my work account in Dropbox (ie my work email,'personal' folders), there are no issues.
When migrating data from a shared folder, I receive the error, can't find parent folder.
What should the parent folder in the MS migration tool be to migrate data from Dropbox to SP?

WORKS:
myemail@domain/parentfolder/etc
DOESNT WORK:
domainname with or without .com
myemail/parent/etc

I must be able to migrate shared data from Dropbox to SP, what is the default parent folder hierarchy name for this process?

Comment: the parent folder in the MS migration tool should be the Dropbox user account that owns the folder you want to migrate. For example, if you want to migrate a folder named “Project X” that belongs to a Dropbox user with the email address “jane.doe@dropbox.com”, then the parent folder should be “jane.doe@dropbox.com/Project X”. I noticed you added an extra "/" at the end. Remove that and see if it works.